# Differentiability in $(0,0)$

Tags: analysis

Let $f(x,y)=e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. I would like to define the points for which $f$ is non-differentiable. Is it sufficient argument that $f$ is non-differentiable in $(0,0)$ because $\sqrt x$ is non-differentiable in $(0,0)$, or should I prove it by definition? Or maybe there is a quick way to prove it without using a definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove that one of the partial derivatives, with respect to either $x$ or $y$, does not exist when the other variable is zero.  Set $y=0$.  Then using the Taylor's expansion for the exponential function,
\begin{align}
\left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right \rvert_{x,y=0}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\sqrt{x^2}}-1}{x} \\
&=\lim_{x\to0} \Big( \frac{|x|}{x}+\frac{1}{2!}x + o({x^2} ) \Big)
\end{align}
which (accepting the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits in this case) has limit $\pm1$ depending on the sign of $x$, so $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is differentiable at $0$ because $$f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\partial _xf(0,0)x-\partial _yf(0,0)y=e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1\to0$$
if $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.